# XSLT reordering XML tags during standard copy

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using the following to copy XSLT content as is. But this is re-ordering the xml tags. Is this a bug in Microsoft's XSLT transformation. I am doing this from C#. Copied both C# code and xsl file content below

C# code:

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(data));
XslTransform xsltransform = new XslTransform();
//Load the stylesheet.
xsltransform.Load(xslFile);

// transform
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    xsltransform.Transform(doc, null, sw);

    // save to string
    outputText = sw.ToString();
}
```

xsl content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
<xsl:template match="Root">
  <Root>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From:

```
<Root>
<one>
  <one-1>
    <one-2>
    </one-2>
  </one-1>
</one>
<two>
  <two-1>
    <two-2>
    </two-2>
  </two-1>
</two>
</Root>
```

To:

```
<Root>
<one>
 <two>
  <two-1>
    <two-2>
    </two-2>
  </two-1>
 </two>      
</one>
<one-1>
  <one-2>
  </one-2>
</one-1>
</Root>
```

Comment: Does the input really have a missing close tag for `<Root>` ?  Also, show the complete XSL.  Just because you have a valid identity transform doesn't mean something else in the stylesheet is not interfering.

Comment: Closing </Root> is actually not missing. Stackoverflow's code view chopped it. I've updated the post with my full xsl.

Comment: You have to indent 4 spaces or tags get filtered out.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: If you are using C#, then you probably should be using [XslCompiledTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the transformation. Not that I expect it make a difference as I find it hard to believe even `XslTransform` would have a bug like this. Are you sure the XSLT you have shown is the actual one being run? Perhaps `xslFile` is actually referring to an older, different, XSLT?

Comment: See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiHN for the transform being run with XslCompiledTransform